# Is it possible to write comment for UDT in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, comments, cassandra-3.0, user-defined-types

In Cassandra, for tables we can write a comment as follows:

`CREATE TABLE company.address(
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   street text,
   ...
) WITH COMMENT = 'Table containing the address of company
    id      - unique identifier of a company,
    street  - street of the company';`

But for UDT(user defined type) I can't find if there is a way for writing a comment where I want to provide a description for each field of UDT. Is that possible in Cassandra ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments for columns are not possible in cassandra 3.x (latest available version).

Jira Ticket for the same [CASSANDRA-9836](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9836).

As of now best bet is to use self explanatory column names.

Comment: I don't need a comment for columns. In case of table I write a description for  columns inside the comment of table(i've edited my post, see there), but UDT seems does not support a comment at all.

Comment: yes.. Jira ticket has raised request for same... then describe your UDT in table comment as well

Comment: As of now comment is not possible for UDT,UDF,UDA... etc

Comment: It means that I have to describe the UDT in every table it is used, and then maintaining a change in UDT will become a nightmare. Hmm, strange that V3 still does not support a comment for UDT.

Comment: better will be to keep separate documentation... I don't get the case where you have to add comment like `street of company` for `street` column in `company` table... Atleast not as table comment

Comment: The reason of keeping the fields' description in table comment is to be able to understand the fields' meaning when you look into the database and execute `DESCRIBE TABLE xxx`. There is no any other option apart writing that info in table comment itself